# Dynamically resize JPanels to fit width of window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I've got an arbitrary number of JPanels being created based on user input (like 1-8 panels). Right now, I'm putting all the panels in a larger panel using FlowLayout, and then adding that panel to my main window which is using BoxLayout. I want the panels to fit the width of the main window but right now they are very small. Should I use a different layout or is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to choose `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use a different layout manager. Use BorderLayout (tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)), which streches all the contents to fit the container.

Also, BorderLayout doesn't allow more than one component in each area, thus you will need another sub-panel to hold your panels. Don't use FlowLayout for that sub-panel, as it will not have the streching behaviour your are looking for.